# Trying to get either one of two panels to slideToggle when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle, panels

I'm trying to create a code that makes one of two panels slide down when a button is pressed. Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/06szhymc/82/

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#imageslider").click(function(){
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  then if(rand==1){
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        }else{
$("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="imageslider">Press<button>
    <div id="panel"><div id="panel"><div class="paneltest" style="background-color:black; color:white; padding:20px;">

<h2>Paris</h2>

<p>Paris is in France</p>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>
<p>Standing on the Seine Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>

</div> </div></div>
    
    <div id="panel2"><div id="panel2"><div id="paneltest" style="background-color:black; color:white; padding:20px;">

<h2>London</h2>

<p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
<p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>

</div> </div></div>
```

I would also like to have the panels be invisible (display:none) before the button is pressed, so that one or the other appears.

I can't see what's wrong with my code. Any help would deb much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed up many tags.

First your javascript closing of functions are not taken care properly. Try and use an IDE if you are a beginner to understand if you have any missing braces.

Second with your html, you have to understand how to enclose the elements in one another because, what you have there is something with two same `id`'s and a button is not closed properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#imageslider").click(function() {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    if (rand == 1) {
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    } else {
      $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
    };
  })
});
```

```html
<button id="imageslider">Press</button>
<div id="panel1">
  <div class="paneltest" style="background-color:black; color:white; padding:20px;">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p>Paris is in France</p>
    <div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>
    <p>Standing on the Seine Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  <div id="paneltest" style="background-color:black; color:white; padding:20px;">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    <div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For ensuring the div's are invisible at first, you can add

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#panel1").hide();
    $("#panel2").hide();
 ..
 ..
```

**Update**
Here is what you can do to get one toggle on another just on visibility

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#panel1").hide();
    $("#panel2").hide();
    $("#imageslider").click(function () {
        if (!($('#panel1').is(':visible'))) {
            $("#panel1").slideDown("slow");
            $("#panel2").hide();
        } else if (!($('#panel2').is(':visible'))) {
            $("#panel2").slideDown("slow");
            $("#panel1").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong, its bascally, you are looping based on `Math.random` and trying your luck to get `1` every time. Which is something not predictable. If you want both of them to toggle, think of condition where your `if` statement can execute.

Comment: I used your guidance to get it close to what I want (http://jsfiddle.net/xq2241j6/11/) but each time the button is pressed, the panels continue to slide down until every panel is displayed. I'm now working on adding "&&" conditions to the if/else statements. I feel as though I need to set the conditions such that they say something along the lines "if (rand == 1 && [#panel2 is hidden]//<<not sure how to code that// $("#panel1").slideDown("slow")...etc. In other words, the panel will only slide down if the other panel is hidden. Advice on how I can format this && condition is much appreciated

Comment: Glad to know my answer has helped you. For `[#panel2 is hidden]<<<not sure how to code that] ` you can check `$("#panel2").is(":visisble")`

Comment: I'm so sorry to keep bothering you - last time hopefully. I added the multiple conditions to the if/then statements, and it just totally stopped it from working now. Could you please take a quick glance at what I did wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/xq2241j6/25/

Comment: Firstly, no need to be sorry :), secondly, again you have missing braces in javascript and had multiple ready function. Then now see my update. Thirdly, if you have found the answer helpful, do select so. ;)

Comment: Awesome! It works. I tried to up-vote your answer, but it said that I need a "reputation of 15" to do so